# Как установить VSCode на Macbook M1?

Tags: visual-studio-code, install, macbook, m1

Всем привет!
Не могу установить VSCode на Macbook M1
Прочитал руководства, но, кажется они писались до 2022 года
Теперь Apple не дает так просто устанавливать программы на процессоры M1

При попытке установить VSCode получаю вот такую ошибку:
Это приложение недоступно в вашей стране или регионе
Что делать? Памагити!)

Comment: Под vpn ставьте, хз.. Дело не в М1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Установка Visual Studio Code**

1. [Загрузите Visual Studio Code](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=534106) для macOS.
2. Откройте список загрузки браузера и найдите загруженное приложение или архив.
3. Если архив, извлеките содержимое архива. Используйте двойной щелчок в некоторых браузерах или выберите значок «увеличительное стекло» в Safari.
4. Перетащите Visual Studio Code.app в папку Applications, чтобы он стал доступен на панели запуска macOS.
5. Откройте VS Code из папки «Приложения», дважды щелкнув значок.
6. Добавьте VS Code в Dock, щелкнув правой кнопкой мыши значок,расположенный в Dock, чтобы открыть контекстное меню, и выбрав «Параметры», «Сохранить в Dock».

**Запуск из командной строки**

Вы также можете запустить VS Code из терминала, введя «code» после добавления его в путь:

- Запустите VS Code.
- Откройте палитру команд (Cmd+Shift+P) и введите «shell comand», чтобы найти команду оболочки: Install 'code' command in PATH command.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Перезапустите терминал, чтобы новое значение $PATH вступило в силу. Вы сможете ввести «code». в любой папке, чтобы начать редактирование файлов в этой папке.

> **Примечание.** Если у вас есть старый алиас для запуска кода в вашем .bash_profile (или эквивалентном) из ранней версии VS Code, удалите его и замените, выполнив команду оболочки: **Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH**

Comment: Спасибо большое! Установил
Но теперь другая проблема:
Git тоже установил, но VSCode не видит Git, пишет: Download Git for MacOS - предлагает установить Git
Хотя в терминале VSCode я набрал команду: 
```
git --version
git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
```
то есть Git установлен
Но VSCode его не видит и я не могу клонировать репозиторий
Что делать?

Comment: Где он пишет `Download Git for MacOS` ? Если в терминале вводите, значит гит установлен, все верно.

Comment: я не знаю как тут вставить скриншот

Download Git for MacOS - пишет в колонке слева вверху, там где по идее должно быть написано "Клонировать репозиторий"

вот загрузил на хостинг картинок: https://ibb.co/D10qY4k

Comment: Это расширение VS Code, загляните в расширения, где иконка кубиков. Если надо, установите его. Если расширение не нужно, можно через консольку вводить команды git, и все будет хорошо :)

Comment: Просто наберите `git clone <ссылка>` в терминале vs code

Comment: спасибо огромное! git clone <ссылка> - вот это сработало!

Comment: Был рад помочь!